# Trying to add specific values from a matrix without using numpy

Tags: python

I am supposed to create a function that adds the absolute value of numbers that are larger than a certain number without using any python modules to do it. I wrote this:

```
def MatrixSumLarge(vals,large):

    sum=0
    sum1=0
    sum2=0
    i=0

    #looking at the rows of the matrix
    for i in range(len(vals[i])):
        if abs(vals)>=large:
            sum1=sum1+i

        #lookinng at the columns of the matrix
        for j in range(0,len(vals[j])):

            if abs(vals[j])>=large:
                sum2=sum2+vals[j]

    sum=sum1+sum2

    return(sum)

vals=[[1,-2.5,7,4],[-8,9,2,-1.5],[-12,7.5,4.2,11]]

# setting value of large
large = 7.1

#to print the final answer
print('b) Sum of Large Values = ',MatrixSumLarge(vals,large))
```

And got the error:

> TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'list'

Answer (score 0):

You `vals` is a list of list, so `vals[i]` is a list. However, `abs()` cannot be applied on a list, it should be applied on a number (floating number, integer, or complex number), see the [official document here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#abs). You can for example, add an extra loop to add up the element in the row, like `sum(abs(x) for x in vals[i] if x >= 2)`

You can change `2` to the number you need.

Overall, your function could look something like this

```
def f(mat, v):
    row_sums = [sum(abs(x) for x in row if x >= v) for row in mat]
    return sum(row_sums)
```

From your question, it's not very clear to me whether you wanna

- compare `abs(x)` to `v` or `x` to `v`
- sum up `abs(x)` or `x`

But you should be able to adjust the code above to suit your need.

There is also a python module that helps you to flatten list of list. The function is called [chain.from_iterable](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable). So the above code could also be written like this

```
from itertools import chain

def f(mat, v):
    sums = [sum(abs(x) for x in chain.from_iterable(mat) if x >= v]
    return sum(sums)
```